# Run Angular 5 app in IE without using "import 'core-js/es6/reflect' and import 'core-js/es7/reflect'"

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular2-routing, angular-services

How to run angular 5 app in IE without using these two library.

```
import 'core-js/es6/reflect' 
import 'core-js/es7/reflect'
```

I cannot use these two modules because of unsafe-eval issue. But without these, I am unable to run Angular code on IE.

Answer (score 0):

They thought about that. At the root of your Angular-CLI project, there is a `polyfill.ts` file.

Uncomment the necessary polyfills :

```
/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/

import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
import 'core-js/es6/object';
import 'core-js/es6/function';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es6/number';
import 'core-js/es6/math';
import 'core-js/es6/string';
import 'core-js/es6/date';
import 'core-js/es6/array';
import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

Also, for .includes() support, add this line :

```
import 'core-js/es7/array';
```

Comment: Hi, this is not the question actually i have Uncomment the necessary polyfills and in IE its already working fine, but now i have to deploy my app to secure server where i am getting 'unsafe-inline' and  'unsafe-eval' error. To solve this issue i have to comment  reflect modules but then in IE its not working.

Comment: Aaaah, I get it now. Unfortunately I have no idea how to get around this :/